# Is it possible to display double with larger precision than a float via String Formatter?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, precision

How can I keep precision when working with doubles in Java? I have the following test case:

```
double x = -1.0 / 3.0;
double y = 1.0000000001;
Point2 p = new Point2(x, y);

String expected = "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
assertEquals(expected, p.toString());
```

Point2 constructor:

```
public Point2(double x, double y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  }
```

toString Override:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.format("(%f, %f)", this.x, this.y);
}
```

Which is failing: `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<(-0.333333[3333333333, 1.0000000001])> but was:<(-0.333333[, 1.000000])>`

Comment: What's the source code of `Point2`?

Comment: You're testing the result of p.toString(). What's its code? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I added it to the question. Interestingly I did `double x = Double.MAX_VALUE`, and that worked, however it still only kept 6 decimal places.

Comment: Well, you're using `String.format("(%f, %f)", this.x, this.y)` to print your values. If you want the result to be the same as `"(" + x + ", " + y + ")"`, then use `return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")"`in your toString() method.

Comment: ok great - that worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my toString() method. Makes sense that they were being formatted as floats now. Ended up updated it to :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
}
```

Comment: They're not formatted as floats. They're formatted according to the default locale, and with a default precision (since you didn't specify one) of 6 numbers after the decimal point. That's how String.format() specifies what it does with %f. It doesn't just call toString() on the number as you thought.

Comment: Would there have been a way to use String.format() to display doubles of varying precision (without knowing ahead of time the number of decimal points, eg. 6 or more)?

Comment: I don't think so.